# R convert columns to JSON rowwise

Tags: r, dplyr, jsonlite

I have data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,3),b = c(2,4))

  a b
1 1 2
2 3 NA
```

and I want to receive a data.frame like this:

```
  a  b           json
1 1  2 {"a":1, "b":2}
2 3 NA        {"a":3}
```

I wonder if there is a way to get this result efficiently with

```
df <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(json = ?())
```

without pasting values myself. In Postgres there is a function `json_strip_nulls(row_to_json(*))` to get this. Is there any equivalent in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stream_out` line by line using the awesome *jsonlite* package:

```
library(jsonlite)

df <- data.frame(a = c(1,3),b = c(2,NA))

tc <- textConnection("jsontxt", "w")
stream_out(df, con=tc)
df$json <- jsontxt
close(tc)

df
##  a  b          json
##1 1  2 {"a":1,"b":2}
##2 3 NA       {"a":3}
```

Should be much more efficient than looping by row inside of R:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,3),b = c(2,NA))
df <- df[rep(1:2, 10000),]
rownames(df) <- NULL

system.time({
  tc <- textConnection("jsontxt", "w")
  stream_out(df, con=tc)
  df$json <- jsontxt
  close(tc)
})
##Complete! Processed total of 20000 rows.
##   user  system elapsed 
##   0.78    0.00    0.78 

library(dplyr)
system.time({
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(json = toJSON(across())) %>%
  ungroup()
})
##   user  system elapsed 
##  28.36    0.24   28.61
```

Comment: Usually, I prefer dplyr style, but this is indeed much faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(a = c(1,3),b = c(2,NA))

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(json = toJSON(across())) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 x 3
      a     b json           
  <dbl> <dbl> <json>         
1     1     2 [{"a":1,"b":2}]
2     3    NA [{"a":3}]
```